# Interlocked.Increment an integer array

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

Is this guaranteed to be threadsafe/not produce unexpected results?

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref _arr[i]);
```

My intuition tells me this is not, i.e. reading the value in _arr[i] is not guaranteed to be 'atomic' with the actual incrementing.

If I am correct in thinking this is wrong, how can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Who or what is reading the value in `_arr[i]`? This code doesn't read it, it increments it atomically because that's what `Interlocked.Increment` does.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming nothing changes `i` or `_arr`, that should be fine.

An array is regarded as a collection of variables; an interlocked increment should work fine regardless of what is happening to either that element or others in the same array.

Answer (score 1):

If something *is* asynchronously changing `_arr` or `i` then, I'd agree with you, no, the lookup `_arr[i]` is not necessarily atomic itself.

However, as Jon says, once you have identified an element of (some) `_arr`, *it* will be atomically incremented, independent of other actions happening in other elements of the array(s), or to further changes to `_arr` or `i`.

If `_arr` or `i` are being asynchronously changed, *all* references to them (*both* read and write) need to be inside a `lock` on a common object. (And then you can reduce the `Interlocked.Increment` to a simple `++`.